# Android read error log from handset

Tags: android, logging

How can I read the error log applications make? Is there any software which reads the error log from the handset and displays it?

I don't want to debug the app using eclipse, I'm looking for a handset based error log viewer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a number of free applications in the Android Market which will collect the device log.

One which looks promising is Log Collector, not least because it is open source.  You can find it [on Google Code here](http://code.google.com/p/android-log-collector/) and [on androlib.com here](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-xtralogic-android-logcollector-zpn.aspx).

Here's [another Log Collecting app](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-twofortyfouram-logcollector-iDp.aspx) produced by the creators of [Locale](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-twofortyfouram-logcollector-iDp.aspx).

Comment: Log Collector is a great app.  However if you are debugging on your own device, and not moving around to test GPS or something, having your phone plugged into your PC so you can view the log in real time via DDMS is by far the best way to go.

Comment: @mbaird - I agree but the question did explicitly ask for a handset only solution.

Answer (score 3):

I quite like the one I wrote ;-)
It's called SendLog
http://l6n.org/android/sendlog.shtml

Answer (score 1):

[Alogcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&hl=en) seems OK.  It's a bit verbose, though.