# Android retrieve service crash time

Tags: android, service

I am working on three different services and on device bootup, one service starts other two services. Right now its working fine but some times my service crashes and it restarts itself. I know that this behaviour is common with services, if the memory is low then for reclaiming the memory service restarts itself.

I need to track the service info like getting the service crash time. Right now I retrieve the service start time by  writing code in `onstartCommand()` and stop time in `onDestroy()`.

What I observe is stop time in `onDestroy()` code does not execute when service is crashed. So Is there a way to get the service crash time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few thoughts:

- If it's crashing, it will leave a trace in the log file, there are some comments on reading it here: [Android read error log from handset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147610/android-read-error-log-from-handset)
- If it's being closed by the system in a normal way, it should go through onDestroy.
- If it's going through the slightly mysterious "close, restart" effect that has been reported elsewhere, then it doesn't seem to hit the log, but the two events *seem* to be very close in time, and this effect seems to be stopped by making the services run in separate processed. ([Android service onCreate is called multiple times without calling onDestroy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211066/android-service-oncreate-is-called-multiple-times-without-calling-ondestroy) and possibly [Service being re-Created by AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435117/service-being-re-created-by-alarmmanager)).
- From a state management perspective, if you store the time the service last did something of note (ie keep a stored time of when it does something of note and update it everytime it does something of note) then you will have a good estimate.

Comment: I can actually read the next onStartCommand(), but this wont solve my issue.
There should be a difference between service crash time and stopService() time.
I wanted to know when at what times service crashes.

Comment: I've tried to update the answer to clarify the three scenarios I'm aware of, or is this a different one?